# JQuery SlideToggle() Method li html

Tags: jquery, html

I am an utter nub at JQuery, i just need to figure this one thing out before i start understanding the whole process.

I have used into an LI the below code, i've added float so that the "panel1" onclick opens in the right, and to have the "flip1" on the left. Basically i did nothing but copy/paste from w3schools the SlideToggle() Method and incorporated into "li" and used float. I need to create a list of services by category, onclick opens in the right to show detailed services for that category. **What i need is the onclick "panel1" to close when i click on another "li" with the same set-up.**

```
<ul id="service_list">
<li> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css"> 

#panel1,#flip1

{

padding:2px;

text-align:center;

background-color:#FFFFFF;

float: left;

}

#panel1

{

margin-right:80px;

display:none;

float: right;

}

</style>



<div id="flip1"><a href="#">Service Category</a></div>

<div id="panel1">Services detailed<br>

</div>

<br>

</li>
```

I am sorry if i waste your time, i dont except anyone to even answer. 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't place the script and style tags inside the LI tag, or did you ?

Comment: Create fiddle please.

Comment: Is [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/33zW6/) what you look for? If it is, you just need to place your code in the right place

Answer (score 0):

i think it will help you

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $("#anotherLi").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

</script>


<ul id="service_list">
<li> 

<div id="flip1"><a href="#">Service Category</a></div>

<div id="panel1">Services detailed<br>

</div>

<br>

</li> 
<li id="anotherLi">

<div id="flip2"><a href="#">Service Category</a></div>

<div id="panel2">Services detailed<br>

</div>

<br>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this example fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5spsG/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").hide(); // preferred over starting with "display: none" css
  $(".panel").click(function(){ 
    $("li").hide("slow");
    $(this).find("li").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

The function will hide all li items any time one of the panels is clicked. It will then display only the li for that panel.

Also try to make sure you are separating content from style from behavior as much as possible. Your javascript and css code should be in separate files, or at least contained in separate parts of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want, you don't need to wrap these in an `li` unless you really want to. But you can group them with a container (change the `id`s to classes so you can use them again), and target `$(this)` when you click a category

*UPDATE - I left out the part about closing others when clicked, added that in

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
  var checkForOpen = $(this).closest(".container").siblings().find(".panel");
  var currentPanel = $(this).closest(".container").find(".panel");

  if(checkForOpen.is(":visible")){
    checkForOpen.slideUp(function(){
      currentPanel.slideDown("slow");     
    });   
  }else{
   currentPanel.slideToggle("slow"); 
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QEhLn/3/)